# vim under gnu-screen can't take shift-left/shift-right keymap properly

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I recently started using gnu-screen.
In vimrc, I have 2 keymaps as below to help easy navigation between vim split windows

```
nmap <S-Left> <C-w><Left>
nmap <S-Right> <C-w><Right>
```

Running vim from normal shell, above navigation key maps work as expected.

Running vim from gnu-screen session, these key maps fail, they delete the lines instead!!

I've tried the following:

1. set term=xterm in vimrc
2. set t_kr=^[[1;2C (I wrongly assumed t_kr will help give 'shift-right' properly)

But failed to fix it. Can anyone here please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix!

Using **bindkey/stuff** from gnu-screen and **wincmd** from vim, I updated my screenrc:

```
# Shift + Up-arrow
bindkey ^[[1;2A stuff ":wincmd k^M"
# Shift + Down-arrow
bindkey ^[[1;2B stuff ":wincmd j^M"
# Shift + Right-arrow
bindkey ^[[1;2C stuff ":wincmd l^M"
# Shift + Left-arrow
bindkey ^[[1;2D stuff ":wincmd h^M"
```

Note: '^M' to be added in vim-insert mode using: Ctrl+v then ENTER